# Angular 4 API HttpClient Post/Get in Zomato

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient, zomato-api

I have this function but zomato keeps on returning it as 403 (invalid API). I am not sure if there are other function/parameters that are needed to fill the user-key

```
url='https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search?count=50&lat=111&lon=111&radius=1500&order=desc'
sendGetRequest() {
             const headers = new HttpHeaders()
                 .set('cache-control', 'no-cache')
                 .set('content-type', 'application/json')
                 .set('user-key', 'mykeygoeshere')

             return this.httpClient
                        .get(this.url, '', { headers: headers })
                        .subscribe(res => res.json);
    }
```

Comment: As per web description, you need to generate the API key. Do you have a key?

Comment: Did you try the request with some REST Tool like Postman or curl?

Comment: the key is working properly on a php Curl @PrasadBonthu

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the search request by generating the API key and got the successful response. So you need to have a proper API key.

**Request:**

`curl -X GET --header "Accept: application/json" --header "user-key: a2716934XXXXXXXXXXXX21ced1a5a35" "https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/search"`

**Response:**

```
{
  "results_found": 1272959,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 20,
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "restaurant": {
        "R": {
          "res_id": 17842104
        },
        "apikey": "a2716934XXXXXXXXXXXX21ced1a5a35",
        "id": "17842104",
        "name": "Mr.",
```